# Laravel querying multiple related models

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, query-builder

For example: I have these models in my application.
`User`, `Profile`, `Interest`.

I linked the `users` table with the `profiles` table by adding the `user_id` column in the `profiles` table. And I linked `profiles` and `interests` by using a pivot table (`interest_profile`), Which is (as obvious) will have two columns (`profile_id`, `interest_id`).

However, I want to query the users who are associated with a profile, too see who is associated with a particular interest, In other words: "select all users who are having (in their profiles) that particular interest".

I know that I can do this with raw SQL by joining the four tables and then use (where clause).. But I want to do it the Laravel way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure you have your relationships setup correctly on your models like:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}

class Profile extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function interests()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Interest::class, 'interest_profile');
    }
}

class Interest extends Model
{
    public function profiles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Profile::class, 'interest_profile');
    }
}
```

Then you can use `whereHas()` to constrain a query by a related model and dot notation for nested relations.  So your query would be:

```
User::whereHas('profile.interests', function($query) use ($interestName) {
    return $query->where('name', $interestName);
})->get();
```

That would just return a collection of users.  If you wanted to return their profiles and interests as well you would use `with()`:

```
User::whereHas('profile.interests', function($query) use ($interestName) {
    return $query->where('name', $interestName);
})
->with('profile.interests')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `User` model has a relationship `profile` and the `Profile` model has a relationship `interests`, you can do this.

```
$interest_id = 1;

$users = User::whereHas('profile', function ($query) use ($interest_id) {
    $query->whereHas('interests', function ($query) use ($interest_id) {
        $query->where('id', $interest_id);
    });
})->get();
```